# xamarin android player erro ao iniciar "virtualbox kernel driver not running"

Tags: xamarin

Ao executar o *XAP-Beta-15.35-v0.5.5-i386* obtenho o seguinte erro:

> virtualbox kernel driver not running

Nenhum driver foi instalado no virtualbox e o mesmo não esta rodando.

Comment: Mac OSX, Windows-32bit ou Windows-64bit?

Comment: Windows 7 32 bits

Comment: Parece que o problema e com a versao 0.5.5, tente atualizar pra versao 0.5.6 conforme a resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86628/3635

Comment: Obrigado. Fui no site Xamarin e baixei a versao disponivel em 

https://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/installer/Windows/Xamarin%20Android%20Player%20x32.exe

E funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a postagem no *fórum do xamarin* e pode ser resolvido como mencionado pelo [mridoni](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/149966/#Comment_149966):

> I used this link (I made a couple of attempts to "rewrite" it by hand, starting from the link for 0.4.4):
>
> http://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/player/win/0.5.6/XAP-Beta-15.36-v0.5.6-amd64.exe
>
> The problem is that since the emulator (v0.5.5) doesn't start at all, it never prompts to upgrade from 0.5.5 to 0.5.6. I suppose that if you completely uninstall, then install 0.4.4 (the version available from XAP's main page), then you can upgrade successfully.

Isto quer dizer que o problema ocorre na versão 0.5.5, mas não ocorre no 0.5.6, então basta fazer o updgrade.

- Versão 0.5.6 pra Windows 32bit:

  http://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/player/win/0.5.6/XAP-Beta-15.36-v0.5.6-i386.exe
- Versão 0.5.6 pra Windows 64bit:

  http://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/player/win/0.5.6/XAP-Beta-15.36-v0.5.6-amd64.exe

---

### Extra

> Observação, a versão atual é o 0.6.5, então se puder atualizar para
> este (veja sua compatibilidade e etc):
>
> - Windows 64bit:
>
>   http://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/player/win/0.6.5/XAP-Beta-15.43-v0.6.5-amd64.exe
> - Windows 32bit:
>
>   http://xamarin-android-player.s3.amazonaws.com/player/win/0.6.5/XAP-Beta-15.43-v0.6.5-i386.exe
>
> Para futuras atualizações acesse:
> https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

Answer (score 0):

1. instale a versão mais recende do XAP (0.5.6)
2. Se o seu windows for 8.1 ou 10 baixe no site da Oracle a ultima
   versão do VM Virtual Box(a versão instalada pelo XAP é incompatível)
3. Ao instalar a nova versão do VM Virtual Box certifique de que o mesmo instalou os drivers
4. Verifique seu firewall ou anti vírus se eles não bloquearam o processo de rodar(difícil de acontecer mas não custa nada tentar)